# Why can't I declare a type of friend function by template parameter but can with alias

Tags: c++, templates, friend

Consider the code:

```
template <class T>
class Bar {
    int foobar;
    using X = T();
    friend X foo;
};

void foo() {
    Bar<void> bar;
    bar.foobar = 1;
    static_cast<void>(bar);
}

int main() {}
```

Compiles fine in both [gcc](https://wandbox.org/permlink/qDdOcircf2OSQnTf) and [clang](https://wandbox.org/permlink/mVOoSNN8cHxrDYFc). But seemingly equivalent code:

```
template <class T>
class Bar {
    int foobar;
    friend T foo;
};

void foo() {
    Bar<void()> bar;
    bar.foobar = 1;
    static_cast<void>(bar);
}

int main() {}
```

causes error in both [gcc](https://wandbox.org/permlink/WI1EAhztaQFFlbIo) and [clang](https://wandbox.org/permlink/SKpKfTMc5zRKqOSg). How come the template parameter doesn't work here equivalently to alias?

Comment: Took me a moment to notice you send `void` in one, and `void()` in the other.

Comment: "crash" doesn't usually mean what you are using it to mean.

Comment: And, https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp#spec-7

Comment: @T.C. sorry - editing

Comment: Well... I think T.C. settled it...

Comment: yep that was quick. @T.C. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `T foo` is parsed as the declaration of an object, and instantiation of a template cannot change a declaration of an object to a declaration of a function.

C++ standard/[temp.spec]:

> If a function declaration acquired its function type through a dependent type (17.7.2.1) without using the
>   syntactic form of a function declarator, the program is ill-formed.

Comment: Yep, it is weird though, as you cannot declare an object as a friend but I think this is the underlying cause. Thanks!

Comment: Yes indeed, it is weird. Actualy compilers know that friend cannot be an object  and as an object declaration cannot transform to a function declaration, they anticipate the problem and report the bug before any instantiation.